# Multiple Values Per Element in Java Array

Tags: java, android, arrays, multidimensional-array

I was wondering if there is a way to store more than 2 elements of information per item in an array of items.

For example, for an array of Cities I would like to store Population (int), Name (String), Mayor (String), Is there an airport (boolean).

I need a modifiable list, e.g. one where I can add and access elements easily by their position.

Comment: wouldnt java.util.List work ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a class called `City`, and containing the necessary fields: `population`, `name`, `mayor`, `airportPresent`.

Use a `java.util.List<City>` (`java.util.ArrayList` being usually the best choice as an implementation).

Java is an OO language. Use objects to store your information, and encapsulate behavior. Using multi-dimensional arrays is not the appropriate solution.